# ASP.NET MVC switch language and keep the model data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have switch language helper that change between languages ,
when i change language  i want to keep modal data,

example i open view on English language and fill settings as shown:
[image]

i want when i change language to Arabic to keep model data like this:
[image]

the language helper is action link so it go to controller-> action (Get http) and return view with model.

any method to keep modal data when change language , and i would not put model data in query string because maybe there are big views data.

Comment: How are you populating the model data currently?

Comment: now the switch language redirect to referral  URL , so i go to [Get http] action in controller and i get my view model as usual, some model ire return new instance from model and others i get data from DB fill the model and return the view

Comment: Can you please show a code example of how you're loading your model?

Answer (score 0):

> the language helper is action link so it go to controller-> action (Get http) and return view with model.

So instead of returning a completely new, empty form, why don't you add the form's model into your Get action, and return that, so your form is going to be populated with the data already entered.

Even though I would consider using Resources and UI cultures to switch between languages. [Here's a nice tutorial for you.](http://blog.learningtree.com/internationalizing-asp-net-mvc-applications/)